# Get Current Location using Winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, localization

can anyone help me with retrieving the current location using winapi?
By location i mean Control Panel/Regional & Language/ Location.

Answer (score 0):

See

[GetUserDefaultLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318135%28VS.85%29.aspx)

and

[GetUserDefaultLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318136%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but GetUserDefualtLCID returns the default locale related to COntrol Panel/Region&Language/Formats. I need to get only the current location also known as Geographic ID.

Comment: "current location also known as Geographic ID" I have no idea what that is supposed to be. I probably can't help you.

Comment: Info about location here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688121 , at Location or Geographic ID, but i cannot find any api to query that value

Answer (score 0):

Pass [`LOCALE_IGEOID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373775%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (or `LOCALE_SENGCOUNTRY` if appropriate) to [`GetLocaleInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).